# How do you create a ?Sized type from a raw pointer?

Tags: pointers, rust, unsafe

Here is an example of how to transmute a `Sized` type from a raw pointer:

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
#[repr(packed)]
struct Bob {
    id: u32,
    age: u32,
}

unsafe fn get_type<'a, T: Sized>(p: *const u8) -> &'a T {
    mem::transmute(p)
}

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    let bob = Bob {
        id: 22,
        age: 445,
    };
    let bob2: &Bob = unsafe {
        let ptr: *const u8 = mem::transmute(&bob);
        get_type(ptr)
    };
    assert_eq!(&bob, bob2);
}
```

However, for my application I want to be able to get a `?Sized` type instead of a `Sized` type. However, this doesn't work:

```
unsafe fn get_type2<'a, T: ?Sized>(p: *const u8) -> &'a T {
    mem::transmute(p)
}
```

It fails with this error message:

```
error: transmute called with differently sized types: *const u8 (64 bits) to &'a T (pointer to T) [--explain E0512]
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |>
2 |>         mem::transmute(p)
  |>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have tried to give it a `&[u8]` (fat pointer) by converting it using `std::slice::from_raw_parts`, but it fails with pretty much the same error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually cannot for the very reason cited in the error message.

Rust references can be either pointer-sized (for `Sized` types) or *bigger* (for `!Sized` types). For example, if `Trait` is a trait, a `&Trait` reference is actually two fields as defined by [`std::raw::TraitObject`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html).

So, in order to form a reference to an unsized type, you have to:

- identify exactly what kind of unsized type it is (trait? slice? ...)
- pick the right representation (`std::raw::TraitObject`, `std::raw::Slice`, ...)

and then you have to fill in the blanks (there is more than just a pointer).

So, unless you can limit your function to producing `&T where T: Sized`, you cannot just transmute a raw pointer to `&T`.

Comment: got it, so I assume the compiler just magically handles all that for the normal use case? (which is what it meant that `?Sized` is a "compiler intrinsic...) -- also you said `!Sized` and I think you meant `?Sized`

Comment: @cloudformdesign: I did mean `!Sized`. `Sized` means sized, `!Sized` means not-sized (but cannot actually be used as a bound) and `?Sized` means maybe-sized. As for the compiler handling conversions: indeed, the compiler just packs/unpacks as necessary automatically. Note that both the `raw::TraitObject` and `raw::Slice` are unstable as a principle to allow evolution of the underlying representation, and will probably remain unstable "forever" as Rust is not kin on committing to a stable ABI.

Comment: awesome! Thanks for the great overview